# QueryDSL predicate with Spring data repository - convert timestamp to varchar in WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server, jpa, spring-data, jpql, querydsl

I am writing Java code fetching data from SQL Server DB. I am using Spring Data repository and QueryDSL Predicate with findAll(Predicate ..)

I need to implement in the following WHERE clause :

`WHERE CONVERT(nvarchar(24),myTable.Time_Stamp,21) > "some date as string"`

It works as SQL in SQL Server Studio.

Here is how I define the Predicate in QueryDSL:

`BooleanExpression nextEvents  = Expressions.stringTemplate("CONVERT({0}, {1}, {2})","nvarchar(24)", myTable.timeStamp, "21").gt("some date as string");`

I get the following exception:

`Incorrect syntax near '@P0'.`

Here are the where caluse of the query and the bindings that Hibernate produces:

```
where CONVERT(?, unifiedent0_.Time_Stamp, ?)>? order by unifiedent0_.Time_Stamp asc offset 0 rows fetch next ? rows only
: binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [nvarchar(24)]
: binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [21]
: binding parameter [3] as [VARCHAR] - [2022-09-20 09:56:32.077-113]
```

It all looks correct to me : 3 ? signs and bindings that I expect to see.

What is wrong with the queryDSL expression?

Thank you.

Comment: Aside... avoid doing date/datetime comparisons using strings, that will prevent SQL Server making use of any indexes you might have on the date/datetime columns. Why aren't you using a Date or DateTime instances on the Java side?

Comment: Hi.
The official reference for QueryDSL is really brief. I could not find any example there.
Could you please provide an example of Date or DateTime for the requirement in the question? Let's ignore the motivation for this solution , I just need to do it this way.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to ditch QueryDSL and use JPQL.

It did the job.

The Query is:

```
    @Query("SELECT uem FROM UnifiedEntityMessage uem "
            + "WHERE convert(nvarchar(24),uem.timeStamp,21) + '-' + trim(str(uem.id)) > :lastSentCompositeKey "
            + "and uem.pId in :pids "
            + "and uem.timeStamp < :before "
            + "and uem.type <> :type")
```